# Groovy gsp grails number format replace

Tags: grails, groovy, numbers, format, gsp

I have a German customer, he wants some numbers on his page to be

> `4,3`

instead of

> 4.3

as I cant set the Number format globally for the project or controller because i have javascript depending on the english format, I'm looking for a simple replace method in gsp something like

```
${number.replace(/./,",")}
```

but that causes

> No signature of method: java.lang.Double.replace() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

any idea ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing string conversion stuff, do it like this:

```
${formatNumber(number: number, locale: Locale.GERMAN, format: '##0.00')}
```

Comment: Yaeh thats it,too. I will mark this as Answer because it is more correct to use native numbers thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

take a look at
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/formatNumber.html

You should be able to format the number properly using the locale.